# Mocking ES6 class method in Jest with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, supertest

I've been struggling with this for the past week, so I finally need to admit that I don't know why this is happening.

I'm using supertest with express and TypeScript to test the implementation of some of my API routes. Keep in mind, I'm actively opening a db connection and writing to the DB here, and not using mocks for these methods.

However, I have a dependency in some of my controllers that rely on a logger instance attached to each controller (which is just an ES6 class).

I'm trying to figure out why it's not mocking it properly with the code below:

`utils/logger.ts`:

```
class Logger {
  private filename: string

  public constructor(filename: string) {
    this.filename = filename
  }

  public debug(message: string) {
    console.log('debug:', message)
  }
}
```

`controllers/user.ts`

```
class UserController {
  public logger: any

  constructor() {
    this.logger = new Logger('UserController.ts')
  }

  async create(req: Request, res: Response) {
    this.logger.debug('creating') <-- THIS KEEPS ERRORING with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'logger' of undefined
    return res.status(200).end()
  }
}

export default new UserController()
```

`server/routes/user.ts`:

```
import users from '../controllers/user'

class UserRoutes {
  constructor(server: any) {
    server.post('/api/v1/users/create', users.create)
  }
}

export default UserRoutes
```

here is the app server I'm passing to `supertest`:
`server.ts`:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import express from 'express'
import database from '../server/db'
import Routes from '../server/routes'

class TestApp {
  public server: any
  public database: any

  constructor() {
    this.initDatabase()
    this.run()
  }

  public async run(): Promise<void> {
    this.server = express()
    this.middleware()
    this.routes()
  }

  private middleware(): void {
    this.server.use(bodyParser.json())
  }

 private routes(): void {
    new Routes(this.server)
  }

  public initDatabase(): void {
    this.database = new database()
  }

  public closeDatabase(): void {
    this.database.close()
  }
}

export default TestApp
```

And finally the actual test:

```
import express, { Application } from 'express'
import request from 'supertest'
import TestApp from './server'
let server: any

const initServer = () => {
  jest.mock('../server/controllers/user', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        logger: {
          debug: jest.fn()
        }
      }
    })
  })

  const testApp = new TestApp()
  const server: Application = testApp.server
  const exp = express()
  return exp.use(server)
}

beforeAll(async () => {
  server = initServer()
})

describe('POST /api/v1/users', () => {
  test('should create a new user', async () => {
    const res = await request(server)
      .post('/api/v1/users/create')
      .send({
        username: 'testing'
      })
      expect(res.status).toEqual(200)
  })
})
```

I've tried mocking both the instance of `logger` in the user controller AS WELL AS the actual `logger.ts` entire class, but nothing has been working so far. Here's the full stack trace:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'logger' of undefined

  46 |     
> 47 |     this.logger.debug('creating user')
     |          ^
  48 |
  49 |     try {
  50 |       const user = await User.create({

  at src/server/controllers/user.ts:47:10
  at src/server/controllers/user.ts:8:71
  at __awaiter (src/server/controllers/user.ts:4:12)
  at create (src/server/controllers/user.ts:50:16)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at next (node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
  at Route.dispatch (node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
  at Function.process_params (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
  at next (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
  at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:343:9)
  at SessionStrategy.authenticate (node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:75:10)
  at attempt (node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:366:16)
  at authenticate (node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:367:7)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
  at trim_prefix (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
  at node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
  at Function.process_params (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
  at next (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)

  console.log src/server/controllers/user.ts:46
```

Why is `this` (the user controller instance) always `undefined`?

Comment: Could you show how you use UserController? I guess you may pass a method of the class as a handler like `app.post('/user', userController.create)` in this case, it would lose the context and you need to bind it to the instance or define it as a property.

Comment: @Shlang that makes sense, but how can I make sure to not lose the context? Typically I'd assume using `bind` or `call`, but where? (Also updated to show the `routes.ts` where the method is called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you lose the context:

```
server/routes/user.ts

server.post('/api/v1/users/create', users.create)
```

There are a few options to avoid it

1. Define the method as a property in your controller

```
controllers/user.ts

class UserController {
  // ...
  create = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    this.logger.debug('creating');
    return res.status(200).end();
  }
  // ...
}
```

2. Bind the method to the instance (it creates one more funtion)

```
server/routes/user.ts

class UserRoutes {
  constructor(server: any) {
    server.post('/api/v1/users/create', users.create.bind(users));
  }
}
```

3. Almost the same as previous one but with arrow function instead of `bind`

```
server/routes/user.ts

class UserRoutes {
  constructor(server: any) {
    server.post('/api/v1/users/create', (req, res) => users.create(req, res));
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. I've used the fat arrow bind, `bind`, `call` for years but for some reason I was chasing the problem and attempting to mock it with Jest. thank you SO so much. <3